# Opinions for motorhome mains AC switching circuit design

Tags: ac, mains, switching

We are located in Europe, and building a motorhome. Currently I plan the electrical wiring for the mains 230V AC.

We will use a 24V / 230V 2kW inverter from battery, but when we have the possibility we would also use external AC. For the safe switching between the internal and external power, I designed a circuit, with the following points in mind:

- for external power, we plan to use the EU standard mains plug (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schuko), because this is what we can find on most places in Europe (* we not really use campsites, rather wild camping and / or staying at friends places)
- the inverter and the external source is not allowed to be connected at the same time
- when the external power is used, we would like to automatically charge the motorhomes battery bank
- if the external power source has any faulty or abnormal wiring (eg. the order of the L, N, E is incorrect, or any of them is missing) the isolation relays should not engage
- the motorhome must have his own RCB and MCB, which we will use also for the inverter and external power

So I've came up with the following schematic, which I also built and tested for all the possible cases: it should work only if all 3 wires are present and all are in the correct order. Please take a look and **tell your opinion, if it is safe or if it can be optimised in any way?**

*to make things a bit more easy to follow:

0)
**all the relays have small current coils (less than 6mA), so they will not trip any existing RCB** (the lowest rated RCB on the market is 15mA, this coil uses 3 times less current)

1)
R7 is there for the case when the L and N are present and are in the correct order, but E is missing. In this case the current goes through both relays, K2 and K1. But because the current is weak, causes an abnormal functionality, sometimes engages the relays, sometimes not. For a safe function, if there is no earth, it must not engage K2, and must engage K1. R7 helps for both relays, in this aspect.

2)
K0 is used to completely isolate the external power, not only L and N, so if from any reason it is high voltage on the E line (faulty earth), it should not output on the whole vehicle. It is connected only if the external power has a safe ground

3)
SA on the schematic is a 255V surge arrester

Thanks!

[image: schematic]

Comment: There are inverters that will auto switch to external when it is available - Trace is one example of a manufacturer.

Comment: yup, i'm aware of this, but they are much more expensive, and we already have an existing victron smart 24/2000 inverter, which unfortunatley is not smart enough for auto switch...

Comment: K1.1 and K2.1 are likely to trip the campsite RCD/ELCB/GFCI. Why do you care about mains "polarity"? In much of Europe plugs are reversible.

Comment: Yes, but Trace has considered many more safety issues than you have...

Comment: Regarding campsite RCD, I forgot to mention they are small current coils, less than 6mA. Edited my post. Sorry. Regarding "polarity", yes, it is not a big deal, but it is just extra piece of mind and it also makes the motorhomes RCB beeing in the correct way wired.

Comment: What is a "standard EU plug" to you? Also, you seem to rely on current flowing in earth wire, and that would trip the upstream RCD and cut power to your car immediately on connection. Do consult an electrician how to do it safely, as most likely you are not an electrician and most likely under your local jurisdiction you are not allowed to do this kind of electrical work without being an electrician or have the work you do approved by an electrician, for safety reasons.

Comment: I edited my post regarding the RCD, the coils do not pass enough current to trip it. Tested and it works. By standard EU plug I mean the standard mains plug used in the European Union, see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schuko

Comment: EU has many plugs, the Schuko may not be so common like you think. Campsites tend to have special national plugs that are better to handle outdoors environment and rough handling, such as the blue CEE17 plugs. Choose a good robust connector and be prepared with adapters.

Comment: @WanekT, you are mistaken about the “standard” plug you will find on a campsite. These will almost always be CEE17 (which are polarized by the way). I would seriously consider not bothering with building something myself. Victron (which you already own equipment of) has Auto Transfer Switches for less than €300.

Comment: i see. the cee17 looks really good. the problem is, that campsites have so many plug types, especially in eastern europe... one can carry tens of adapters. this is why i thought to just use the schuko, because every building has at least one. and there are also robust "industrial" grade schuko plugs, with some IP rating.

Comment: @StarCat, AFAIK, those auto transfer switches from victron are not for high power equipment, at least i'm not aware of any models which are for high currents... and they do not detect a faulty or missing ground, or other anomalies etc, just simply switch the source. as for the building, it took me around one day to design and build it, and less than 80 euro.

Comment: The one I found is for up to 5kW. How much do you need?

Comment: send me a link please. i'm aware only about the filax 2. thanks! 5kw should be fine.

Comment: Another idea that I have implemented in our caravan, is to use a main rated DPDT (16A/240VAC) relay with 220-240V AC coil rating. The common contact powers the vehicle's consumers and the the coil determines which of the two entries takes priority. I have wired it to the inverter.

Comment: @gommer, this is exactely what i did, just used more relays to add more safety features.